# iPhone: Change application Bundle files

Tags: iphone, file, bundle

in my application bundle, there are a XML file. i want to change this XML with other XMl file which have same name (without open Xcode). so i want to ask that whether there are any problem arise when i run this application in iPhone

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to modify your application bundle, then you will invalidate the signature on the app and it will not install anymore.  All modifications to items in your bundle, have to happen before Xcode builds it and signs it.

Same thing if your app itself modifies (or tries to modify) your bundle on the iPhone.

Comment: hi,
please suggest me for my approach
i just want to open the APP in windows mode and change the XML file and after that shift to mac mode and then install it on iPhone. if this approaches i use then it is supported or not ?

Comment: Before an app can be submitted to the app store, it needs to have a valid signature.  That signature is created by Xcode.  If you modify your app, after Xcode adds a signature, then you make the siganture invalid.  If you want to modify something on a windows machine, then only modify the XML file, and then put that XML file in the resources directory of your Xcode project, and do a build after that.  The new app will include your new XML file and the right signature.